# Union in an abelian category

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, abelian-categories, limits-colimits, universal-property

I'm working on the following exercise. I have most of it, but there's one detail at the end that I can't work out.

> Let $\{A_i\}$ be a family of subobjects of an object $A$. Show that if $\mathcal{A}$ is abelian and cocomplete  then there is a smallest subobject $\sum A_i$ of $A$ containing all the $A_i$.

Most of it is worked out on [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/260791/smallest-subobject-in-an-abelian-category-containing-a-set-of-objects), but I'm confused about how to apply the universal property of the image.

Specifically, $A_i\hookrightarrow A$ are monomorphisms and there's an induced map $\coprod A_j\rightarrow A$. The object $\sum A_j$ is simply the image of this map. Suppose that $Y$ is a subobject of $A$ that contains all the $A_i$. Then there are monomorphisms $A_i\hookrightarrow Y\hookrightarrow A$ (and moreover this composition must be the original $A_i\hookrightarrow A$ since subobjects are equivalence classes of monics with the same domain), so there's an induced map by universal property of the coproduct $\coprod A_j\rightarrow Y$.

Now, in order to apply the universal property of the image like the answer suggests, I need for $\coprod A_j\rightarrow \sum A_j\rightarrow A$ to be the same factorization as $\coprod A_j\rightarrow Y\rightarrow A$. This is where I get stuck. I only get that $A_i\rightarrow \coprod A_j\rightarrow \sum A_j\rightarrow A$ is the same factorization as $A_i\rightarrow\coprod A_j\rightarrow Y\rightarrow A$, and $A_i\rightarrow \coprod A_j$ is in general not an epimorphism. Since I can't cancel on the right, I don't know how to satisfy the requirements to use U.P. for image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is immediate from the definition of a coproduct.  By definition, for any collection of maps $f_i:A_i\to A$, there is a *unique* map $f:\coprod A_j\to A$ such that $fs_i=f_i$ for all $i$, where $s_i:A_i\to \coprod A_j$ is the inclusion.  The uniqueness part of this means that if two maps $\coprod A_j\to A$ have the same compositions with $A_i\to\coprod A_j$ for each $i$, then the two maps are equal.

Comment: Embarrassingly obvious. Thank you.

Comment: Without appealing to limits, what should the object be for an intersection object on the same family $\{A_i\}$? That is, a largest subobject of $A$ contained in all the $A_i$?

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is exactly--my answer would be exactly what you said, the "largest subobject of $A$ contained in all the $A_i$".

Comment: My question is, why does such a thing exist? The answer to the original question (the dual one) involved a construction involving the image. Analogously, what should the intersection be? The exercise says to assume $\mathcal{A}$ has products.

Comment: Take the kernel of the map $A\to \prod A/A_i$ obtained from all the quotient maps $A\to A/A_i$.  (I was confused by how you said "Without appealing to limits", since products are a kind of limit!)

Comment: Here, $A/A_i$ means the target of $\text{coker}(A_i\rightarrow A)$?

Comment: Yes, the "quotient maps" I refer to are exactly the cokernels of $A_i\to A$.

Comment: There is likely an obvious answer here as well, but if $Y$ is a subobject of $A$ and of $A_i$ for all $i$, then why is the composition $Y\rightarrow A\rightarrow \prod A/A_i$ zero?

Comment: If you compose with each projection $\prod A/A_i\to A/A_i$, you get $0$, since $A\to \prod A/A_i\to A/A_i$ is the cokernel of $A_i\to A$ and $Y\to A$ factors through $A_i$.  By the universal property of a product, a map $Y\to \prod A/A_i$ is determined by its compositions with all the projections.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a slightly different approach. I haven't checked this in detail though.

Let $(A_i)_{i\in I}$ be your family of subobjects of $A$. For a finite
$I_0\subseteq I$ then $\sum_{i\in I_0}A_i$ is also a subobject of $A$.
Now consider the collection of all these finite sums; these form a directed
system and so have a colimit. Is the image of this colimit in $A$ the
required subobject of $A$?